# TFS2010: Build Configuration Issues

Tags: visual-studio-2010, buildconfiguration, buildconfig

I have customized the build configurations in my solution by deleting the Debug and Release configurations and creating "Dev" and "Test".  Everything builds fine locally but I get the following error (and others like it) when building one of the new configurations in TFS.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets
>   (177): Unable to copy file
>   "bin\CommonServiceFactory.dll" to
>   "C:\MyApp\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\Epsi.Web\bin\CommonServiceFactory.dll".
>   Could not find a part of the path
>   'bin\CommonServiceFactory.dll'.

I'm getting this error for both external and project dependencies.  From the posts I've read it seems to be related to the build configuration changes I've made.  If I set the TFS build to use the "Debug" configuration I do get a warning but it builds successfully.

> C:\MyApp\Sources\MyApp.sln.metaproj:
>   The specified solution configuration
>   "Debug|Any CPU" is invalid. Please
>   specify a valid solution configuration
>   using the Configuration and Platform
>   properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe
>   Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug
>   /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those
>   properties blank to use the default
>   solution configuration.

Any help would be most appreciated.

MSBuild Command:

> MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\2\MyApp\ci.MyApp.acme.com\Sources\MyApp.sln" /m:1 /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\2\MyApp\ci.MyApp.acme.com\Sources\MyApp.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=diagnostic" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\2\MyApp\ci.MyApp.acme.com\Binaries\" /p:Configuration="Dev" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\Builds\2\MyApp\ci.MyApp.acme.com\Sources\MyApp.sln.Any CPU.Dev.vsprops"  /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Diagnostic;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/2603;InformationNodeId=449514;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;TFSUrl=http://tfsServer01:8080/tfs/Core%20Development;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Diagnostic;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you do not have the dll in the bin\ directory. If you can get on the build machine, can you check to see where the assemblies of your projects were built to? Make sure the path to the assemblies is the one used by the copying/publishing task to copy the assemblies to the Binaries_PublishedWebistes folder.

If this doesn't help, can you post the msbuild command-line from the TFS build details log up?

Comment: I don't have access to the build server and don't see the msbuild command-line in the log file. I did notice the msbuild target that is failing:

Done executing task "Copy" -- FAILED. (TaskId:153)
Done building target "_CopyWebApplicationLegacy" in project "MyApp.Web.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:262)

Comment: Found the msbuild command and added it to the question above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't find the command very useful. You should have access to the build drop of your build, can you see if the assembly CommonServiceFactory.dll is dropped there, and what its relative path to your build drop location is. Looking into the msbuild log to see what other errors that caused the two tasks above to fail.

Comment: You were right it was expecting the missing files to be in the bin folder.  I hadn't explicitly added these files to source control so I wasn't expecting them to be requested.  You shouldn't have files in your bin directory checked in so I removed them from the solution and that fixed the issue.  Thanks!